# ArrayList<String> from java to C#

Tags: java, c#, list, arraylist, equivalent

This is Java code, how can I do this with C#

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> test= new  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); 
test.get(index).add(s[1]);
```

Comment: Step one would be learning C# I guess

Comment: Thanks buddy, asking about something in c# doesn't mean that I'm bad, I'm learning and I will still learning programming language. My regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, the class is called `List<T>`

```
static List<List<string>> test = new List<List<string>>();
///...
test[index].Add(s[1]);
```

Some things to take note of:
If test were a local variable, you could have the type inferred:
`var test = new List<List<string>>();`

`List<T>` uses an indexer, so no more methods like `get(index)`

In C#, method names are PascalCase.